# Navigate to record details of record created during a flow

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-flows, navigation

I'm trying to navigate to record details of record that was created during the flow. I tried adding simple lightning component with lightning:navigation on a last screen but instead of redirection i get error:

`This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]`

Any idea how to resolve it ?

component controller:

```
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        let recordId = component.get('v.recordId');
        let navService = component.find("navService");
        let pageReference = {
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                "recordId": recordId,
                 "objectApiName": "Account",
                "actionName": 'view'
            }
        };
        navService.navigate(pageReference);
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you using this in a standalone app or community?

Comment: No, The flow is activated from the url list view button